# Как реализовать операцию сравнения в regexp?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу именно с использованием regexp в JS.
Суть задачи проста:
По входным данным матчить числа N-ой значности. Это первое условие.
Вторым условием является то, что последовательность цифр в числе должна быть не убывающей.

Например, для пятизначных чисел, регулярка должна отобрать такие числа, как 12234 или 11234 или 45678 и т.д.

Желательно использование квантификатора {n} для общей группы, чтобы можно было задавать значность числа в процессе генерации регулярки. Но буду рад любым предложенным вариантам.

Почитав документацию, не удалось найти реализации операции сравнения. Возможно, аппарат регулярных выражений не предназначен для сравнения чисел по весу.

Comment: сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать регуляркой в одну строчку... почему бы обычную функцию checkNumber(n) не написать, она будет возврать true/false

Comment: @АлексейОбухов функцию написать можно) никаких проблем, просто тут спортивный интерес, хочется узнать мнение других по этому вопросу и свериться со своим)

Comment: Вот для начала: `^1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$`, остаётся добавить проверку длины

Comment: В итоге должно сработать что-то вроде `(?=^\d{5}$)^1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$`, здесь в фигурных скобках как раз ваше N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, сравнивать числа regex не умеет, поэтому вам придется самостоятельно задать допустимый порядок: `^1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$` — т. е. любое число единиц (в том числе их отсутствие), затем любое число двоек, ..., любое число девяток

Длину совпадения можно проверить с помощью выражения `^\d{5}$` или даже `^.{5}$`

Для того чтобы проверять оба условия одновременно, необходимо одно из них засунуть в просмотр вперед, в итоге получаем: `(?=^.{5}$)^1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$` или `(?=^1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$)^.{5}$`

Comment: А крышку можно вынести в начало и будет на символ короче :)