# C# Regex. Запретить совпадение с пустой строкой

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть некий паттерн regex `^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$`, который проверяет строку на число.

Всё хорошо, но пустую строку он считает за совпадение. Можно ли этого избежать без `if(value == "")... else Regex...`?

Comment: Можно поставить `+` вместо первой `*`, но только если у вас не бывает чисел без первой цифры, а сразу с точкой типа `.123`

Comment: не, мне нужен именно такой pattern

Comment: Ну, сделайте метод для проверки, например: `bool IsNumbersOnly(string str) => str != null && str.Length > 0 && str.All(char.IsDigit);`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037520/218063 — почти то что вам нужно. Засуньте в просмотр вперёд что-то вроде `^.+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько вариантов условия непустой строки:

```cs
^(?!$)[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
^(?=.|\n)[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
^(?=[\w\W])[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
```

где `^(?!$)` запрещает конец строки в её начале, а `^(?=[\w\W])` и `^(?=.|\n)` требуют наличия хотя бы одного символа в строке.

В данном конкретном случае, наверное, лучшим выражением будет

```cs
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qAJuOV/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[0-9]*` - ноль и более цифр
- `\.?` - опциональная точка
- `[0-9]+` - одна и более цифр
- `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такое решение - добавить негативный проход на соответствие любому символу, который встречается ровно 0 раз:

```
^(?!.{0}$)[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
```